# Trouble using Upstart to launch Redis as redis user

Tags: centos, upstart

I'm trying to launch redis-server as a user (called redis) via Upstart. My /etc/init/redis-server.conf looks like this:

```
description "redis server"

start on runlevel [23]
stop on shutdown

exec sudo -u redis /usr/local/bin/redis-server /var/lib/redis/redis.conf
```

Looks good, right? I start redis-server using

```
$start redis-server
redis-server start/running, process 16808
$redis-cli
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
$ps ax | grep ps 168
16810  tty1    R+     0:00 ps ax
16811  tty1    S+     0:00 grep 168
```

So redis-server definitely isn't running. Let's try executing the Upstart command by hand, shall we?

```
exec sudo -u redis /usr/local/bin/redis-server /var/lib/redis/redis.conf
[16852] 19 Jun 10:37:21 # Can't chdir to './': Permission denied
Connection to 10.19.2.94 closed.
```

And then I get logged off. I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was caused by the redis user not being able to execute the redis-server binary from /home/root. Some research reveals that many folks have had problems using Upstart under CentOS. The eventual solution was to use this [Redis init.d script](https://gist.github.com/257849).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting logged off because when exec complements, the shell exists. This is true whether the command succeeds or fails (try `exec echo hello` for example). So, to avoid getting logged out, use this instead:

```
sudo -u redis /usr/local/bin/redis-server /var/lib/redis/redis.conf
```

That may not solve your issue, but it will make your testing go faster.

Comment: That's one issue down, 99 to go.